# How to attach events to a colorbox popup in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, colorbox

I'm having a lot of issues with events triggering in my colorbox popup.  Currently, there is a backbone view taking care of a user profile page.  There is a gallery of photos, that when clicked, opens a colorbox that contains the photo, as well as comments, comment input form, and like buttons.

The html I put into the colorbox is a hidden div on the template itself.  Everything displays just fine, but clicking things don't trigger anything.  I figured I would try to attach the event handlers to the html I pass into the colorbox function, since I'm guessing the pop up colorbox is not considered to be in the backbone view's dom.  The function is below, which the Backbone view triggers of a click event on an img.  The var photoBox is the html I want to be displayed in the colorbox.  I tried to attach event handlers to the photoBox, but to no avail.

```
 popColorbox: function(event) {
    var photoID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().attr('data-id');
    var photoBox = $("#inline_example" + photoID).parent().html();

    $(photoBox).on('click', '.unlike', function(){
      console.log("hello");
      alert("hello");
    });

    $(photoBox).on('click', '.like', function(){
      console.log("hello");
      alert("hello");
    });

    $.colorbox({html: photoBox});

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption as to why the events aren't being triggered is correct. In backbone view's the [events](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) are delegated to their root `el`, as such since the colorBox's elements are not children of the view's `el` its events aren't being triggered.

The reason why your events aren't being fired when you try binding directly to the *photoBox* I think is because the [colorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) plug-In expects a string of html which it uses to build up it's html (as opposed to just attaching the nodes you pass in).

In order to trigger your events you will need to bind them to some existing *higher* element on the `DOM`, in this case you might need to go up to the document.

```
$(document).on('click', '.unlike', function(){
      console.log("hello");
      alert("hello");
    });

$(document).on('click', '.like', function(){
      console.log("hello");
      alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here the event listener is added on html rather than a selector. Please look at jQuery documentation on adding an event listener. http://api.jquery.com/on/